# Adding stylx-file via ModelBuilder using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, style

Is there a way to add a custom `stylx`-file, I created, to my ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder process?

I would like to auto style the output layer of my process, after the process is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly. The StyleX file is a container of styles. How a style is applied to a feature needs to be defined. You can do that by saving a Layer File (`.lyrx`) that has these mappings. For example, you set a Unique Value Render on a particular field using a symbol defined in the Style file. Once you have this setup, save the layer to the .lyrx and use this file to symbolize your output.

Now that you have a .lyrx, there are two ways to use it:

1. Use the Apply Layer from Symbology tool. Make it the last tool run in your chain, setting it's output layer as a model parameter ('P')
2. Within ModelBuilder, your final output has been set as a parameter ('P'). Save the model. From the Catalog window > Toolbox > your model > right click > Properties, find the parameter, scroll to the end and add the path to your layer file in the symbology column.

Comment: By double clicking the output layer (or the layer to style) you can access the layer properties and there link to the layerx-file aswell.