# Configuring popup within ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, popup

Is there a way to configure popups within a ModelBuilder process using ArcGIS Pro?

I am generating xy-points based on an input table and want to define the popup layout used only for this specific output layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the exact same way my last question was answered:

By exporting a layerx-file with the desired popup-info and the import the layerx-file within the ModelBuilder

Here is the [more detailed answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416425/adding-stylx-file-via-modelbuilder-using-arcgis-pro/416439#416439)

Comment: If the answers are the same, is the question a duplicate?